# How to turn a UNIX executable into a desktop icon shortcut?

Tags: python, macos, unix, ubuntu

I have a python program that is executable and I can run it on my terminal by typing: ./python_file_name

This is fine for my use, but I want the program to be accessible to non-computer people. I would like to be able to create a desktop shortcut that runs the UNIX executable file. Currently when I double click the executable file it just opens the python program in a text editor. I want to be able to have the end-user double click the file so that it executes in the background.

Just for completeness, the script generates a time-sensitive-data-scraping csv file in the user's downloads folder. Therefore, there is no need to create an application with a GUI or anything fancy like that. Also, I am using Ubuntu and the end-user will be on Mac OS X.

Comment: I hope this link will be helpful http://askubuntu.com/questions/481525/python-executable-upon-double-click

Comment: Let's say you have a script called `my.py` - just rename it as a `.command` file, then `chmod +x my.command`. In some cases you might need `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [py2app](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/). It will allow you to send your user a nice little application bundle.